# How to add time to SSIS expression?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I currently use this expression to get the current time:

```
Right("0" + (DT_STR,2,1252) DatePart("hh",getdate()),2) <br>
+ Right("0" + (DT_STR,2,1252) DatePart("mi",getdate()),2)
```

> Example output: 1830

How do I add or subtract hours to account for timezones?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [DATEADD()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141719.aspx) function. So, to add 2 hours to the current date, you'd do something like this:

```
DATEADD(hour, 2, getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not getting what you want but dateadd(hour,5,getdate()) you can use to add hours in date and (DT_DBTIME) GETDATE() you can use to get the time from date